# Which foods can be consumed before a session of Japa?

Tags: mantras, food, japa, health

Are there any foods that one can consume before beginning a long session of Japa, especially if this is a daily occurrence, so as to prevent the development of gastritis? Please give references.

Edit:
Do the scriptures of any sampradaya have anything to say on the matter considering that Japa may be taken up by people of various ages and states of health?

Comment: Sattvic food is recommended overall for any sandhna/japa/meditation etc, plus it should be taken at-least 1.5-2 hrs before your practice to allow proper digestion of food and to prevent laziness. Another thing is to avoid over-eating, stomach should be left partially empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swami Sivananda suggests that light Sattvik food can be taken before doing Japa. Stomach mustn't be fully loaded before doing activities like Japa, Yoga.

Mentioned in his book ["JAPA YOGA - A COMPREHENSIVE TREATISE ON MANTRA SASTRA"](http://japa-yoga.org/japa.pdf)

> If you are tired of repeating the Mantra at one stroke, have 3 or more
> sittings, say, in the morning from 4 O'clock to 7, in the evening from
> 4 to 5, and at night from 6 to 8. Repeat the Mantra very, very quickly
> for sometime, when you find that the mind is wandering much. The
> golden rule is to repeat th Mantra neither too slow nor too quick.
> Observe the happy medium. The Aksharas of the Mantra should be
> pronounced properly. And also, the Mantra should be repeated
> Akshara-Laksha. If there are 5 Aksharas or letter in the Mantra it
> should be repeated 5 lakh times. This is Akshara-Laksha repetition.
> If you sit by th side of a river, lake or well, in a temple, at the
> foot or top of a mountain, in a lovely garden or solitary room, the
> mind will be focused quite easily, without much effort. **If you
> repeat the Mantra, when the stomach is overloaded, you will feel
> drowsy. Take light Sattvic food**. Repeat any prayer and then sit for
> Japa. The mind will then be elevated. You will find it pleasant to
> rotate the beads easily. You must use yoiur common-sense throughout
> your spiritual practice. For sometime you can visit holy places like
> Rishikesh, Haridwar, Varanasi, etc., and there you can do Japa on the
> banks of holy rivers like the Ganga. You will find marked improvement.
> As the mind, while in such sacred places, is free from business,
> worries and family-anxieties, you can have an efficient turn of Japa
> owing to good concentration there. Record the Japa in your spiritual
> diary.

And, by "sattvik light food" he means milk and fruits. This is mentioned elsewhere in the same PDF.

> 15. Never let a day pass without meditation. Be regular and systematic. Take Sattvic food. Fruits and milk will help mental
>     focussing. Give up meat, fish, eggs, smoking, liguors, etc.